# Extraer texto de una columna

Tags: r

Tengo los siguientes datos

```
datos <- read.table(text = 'col1
"ASDF3033121566984 UCA 199994"
"ASDF3033121566998 UCO Juan 129916"
"ASDF3033121567010 UGR 12199918"
"ASDF3033121567019 UCA Juan 121552520"
"9999999"
"ASDF3033121567064 UCA 1299524"
"ASDF3033121567082 Juan UCA 12199"
"ASDF3033121567120 UPO 12159543"
"9999999"
"ASDF3033121594373 USE 126"
"ASDF12345620629818 USE Juan 1206636 123456"
"ASDF12345620629991 UJA 1240 123456"
"ASDF12345620630178 UCO 12448 123456"
"ASDF12345620621526 UCO 12452 123456"
"ASDF12345620621831 Juan UCO 1206283 123456"
"ASDF12345620621909 UCO 126 123456"
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Quiero marcar en otra columna las siguientes letras

```
lista <- c("UCA","UCO","UGR","USE")
datos$col2 <- str_extract(datos$col1, lista)
```

**Datos:**

```
                                         col1    col2
                ASDF3033121566984 UCA 199994      UCA
           ASDF3033121566998 UCO Juan 129916      UCO
              ASDF3033121567010 UGR 12199918      UGR
        ASDF3033121567019 UCA Juan 121552520      <NA>
                                     9999999      <NA>
               ASDF3033121567064 UCA 1299524      <NA>
            ASDF3033121567082 Juan UCA 12199      <NA>
              ASDF3033121567120 UPO 12159543      <NA>
                                     9999999      <NA>
                   ASDF3033121594373 USE 126      <NA>
  ASDF12345620629818 USE Juan 1206636 123456      <NA>
          ASDF12345620629991 UJA 1240 123456      <NA>
         ASDF12345620630178 UCO 12448 123456      <NA>
         ASDF12345620621526 UCO 12452 123456      UCO 
  ASDF12345620621831 Juan UCO 1206283 123456      <NA>
           ASDF12345620621909 UCO 126 123456      <NA>
```

¿Por qué algunas de las letras las extrae y otras no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la función str_extract, espera como segundo parámetro una expresión regular.
Por eso no te lo encuentra.
Cambia por
`lista <- c(" UCA | UCO | UGR | USE ")`
Pongo espacios, porque si encuentra otra palabra con esos caracteres, también te lo daría
Resultado:

> `col1 col2`
> `1                ASDF3033121566984 UCA 199994  UCA`
> `2           ASDF3033121566998 UCO Juan 129916  UCO`
> `3              ASDF3033121567010 UGR 12199918  UGR`
> `4        ASDF3033121567019 UCA Juan 121552520  UCA`
> `5                                     9999999 <NA>`
> `6               ASDF3033121567064 UCA 1299524  UCA`
> `7            ASDF3033121567082 Juan UCA 12199  UCA`
> `8              ASDF3033121567120 UPO 12159543 <NA>`
> `9                                     9999999 <NA>`
> `10                  ASDF3033121594373 USE 126  USE`
> `11 ASDF12345620629818 USE Juan 1206636 123456  USE`
> `12         ASDF12345620629991 UJA 1240 123456 <NA>`
> `13        ASDF12345620630178 UCO 12448 123456  UCO`
> `14        ASDF12345620621526 UCO 12452 123456  UCO`
> `15 ASDF12345620621831 Juan UCO 1206283 123456  UCO`
> `16          ASDF12345620621909 UCO 126 123456  UCO`

Saludos